# Express authentication handling does not function

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite

I am building a demo authentication system using express in combination with sqlite 3. Authentication functions the way it should, but the client does not react to any of the responses such as:

```
res.send('welcome to website');
```

or

```
res.redirect(login.html);
```

or

```
res.redirect('http://google.com');
```

How can I properly handle a login after it is approved?

Server side:

```
app.get('/login/username/:userN/password/:passW', function (req, res) {  
  var username = req.params.userN,
       password = req.params.passW;

       console.log('initiating login');

   db.get('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?', [username], (err, row) => {
     if (row == undefined){
       console.log('login fail (user doesnt exist)')
     }
     else if (row.password == password) {
       res.redirect('http://google.com');
       console.log('user: ' +  username + ' logged in');
     }
     else {
       console.log('login fail (wrong password)');
     }
   })
 });
```

Clientside:

```
    function get(url) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/" + url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    };

    $('#login').click(function server() {
        var username = document.getElementById('user').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('pass').value;
        var url = 'login/username/' + username + '/password/' + password;
        get(url);

    });
```

Comment: You are using `AJAX` that means the `AJAX` request gets redirected not your page. You should redirect from the client side.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was indeed where i went wrong